# By default Localhost added to url provided in href in reactjs

Tags: html, reactjs, href

There is html {state.filtered_result.exmpale.url}  tag in my code. I want to href to open provided link in new window but when I click on the link it opens urk appeded with localhost url with it. for example I want to open [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) in new tab after clicking but when I click on it,it opens a window http://localhost:3000/cluster/1/example.com.How to just open the page at [www.exampel.com](http://www.exampel.com)

Comment: have you tried adding `http://` in front of the url?

Comment: I added http:// and now it's working.Thank you so much.

Comment: show us your using sample code